# (Eigenvalue,eigenvector) pair approximation by linear least squares?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, soft-question, least-squares

The other day I thought about the problem

$$\min_{\bf a}\{\|{\bf Ma}-\lambda {\bf a}\|_2^2+\epsilon\|{\bf a-d}\|_2^2\}$$

For a known triplet ${\bf M}, \lambda, {\bf d \neq 0}$

Minimum would be $0$ if $\bf d=a$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Could this be a start for (eigenvalue,eigenvector) approximation or am I just extra christmas-time wishful?

Comment: I don't understand the need for $\bf d$. Of course, if you know $\lambda$, you can use least-squares to find an eigenvector, but is solving the normal equations cheaper? It requires a matrix-matrix multiplication.

Comment: You may enjoy [this book](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~john/papers/BOOK/B04.PDF).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo $\bf d$ is some candidate eigenvector. Without it I suspect the zero vector would be found as trivial solution. Normal equations are not cheaper, but they give more freedom in adding or modifying regularization terms. We can avoid matrix-matrix multiplication if we have iterative Krylov methods for example.

Comment: When you compute eigenvectors the standard way, you solve a homogeneous linear system. The normal equations in this case are also a homogeneous linear system.

Comment: "Standard way" is not practical for my purposes. Matrices are way too big (and sparse).

Comment: Were you planning to use gradient descent instead of solving the normal equations?

Comment: No. Iterative Krylov methods. Probably Conjugate Gradient or one of it's siblings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can indeed use the question as outline for an algorithm:

$${\bf a_i} = \min_{\bf a}\{\|{\bf Ma}-\lambda_i {\bf a}\|_2^2+\epsilon\|{\bf a-d}_i\|_2^2\}$$

Let us start with ${\bf d}_1, \lambda_1$ either random if we have no clue or as some first guess.

We can devise the following update:

$${\bf d_{i+1} }= {\bf d_{i}- a_{i}}\\\lambda_{i+1} = \delta \cdot \lambda_{i} + (1-\delta)\cdot \text{mean}\left(\frac{\bf Ma_i}{\bf a_i}\right)\\
s.t. \delta \in [0,1]$$
We use $\epsilon = 10^{-1}, \delta = 1/4$ in following experiment.
Below is example log2 plot of error:

[image]

Merry Christmas!